# How to solve the following error in react native

Tags: react-native

When I try to run react-native app using `react-native run-android` command I get the following error. I've searched online I've not found solution for this error

```
    yarn run v1.22.4
    $ react-native run-android
    info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
    Jetifier found 1088 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
    info Starting JS server...
    info Installing the app...
    
    > Configure project :react-native-reanimated
    IOException: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-3.xml
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    IOException: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    IOException: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-1.xml
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    Failed to download any source lists!
    
    IO exception while downloading manifest:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
            at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
...
...
```

How to solve the above issue?

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem. Build tool version 29.0.2 is not installed. I installed from android studio. Now it's working fine.